# How to call an angular 7 function after every on load page

Tags: angular

Hy everone!
Can anyone tell me how to invoke an angular 7 function after each page load?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `router events` in the first page you load (usually `app.components.ts`) and check if the instance of the event is a `NavigationEnd`.
To do so you can have to do this:

```
import { Router,NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
   private router: Router
) {
   this.router.events.subscribe((e) => {
       if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
           // Function you want to call here
       }
    });
}
```

**You have the live example here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-function-stack-55723837?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you so much!
That's what I needed

Comment: This run for all pages, how can I subscribe for specific page?

Answer (score 3):

you can do that in the ngOnInit() method of the app component.

Comment: This is true only after the first loading of the page.
But if I navigate in that page for several times, the ngOnInit method is not re-invoked

Answer (score 0):

Or subscribe to the router NavigationEnd event. See https://angular.io/api/router/Event